# what scale to use for representing years only on x axis in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been developing an area chart for year(x axis) vs Revenue (y axis) in D3 Js.The data is as:

```
localData=[
        {"Revenue":"4.5","Year":"2011"},
        {"Revenue":"5.5","Year":"2010"},
        {"Revenue":"7.0","Year":"2012"},
        {"Revenue":"6.5","Year":"2013"}
       ]
```

I want year at x axis and revenue at y axis for an area chart.Currently I am using time scale for x axis but i dont know how to use it as I have not date format I have only Years to represent.

My Current code is:

```
 var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
                width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
                height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;

            var x = d3.time.scale()
                      .range([0, width]);


            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([height, 0]);
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                            .scale(x)
                            .orient("bottom");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(y)
                .orient("left");


            var area = d3.svg.area()
                .x(function (d) { return x(d.Year); })
                .y0(height)
                .y1(function (d) { return y(d.Revenue); });
            $("#chartArea").html("");
            var svg = d3.select("#chartArea").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                      .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            x.domain(d3.extent(localData, function (d) { return d.Year; }));
            y.domain([0, d3.max(localData, function (d) { return d.Revenue; })]);
            svg.append("path")
                 .datum(localData)
                 .attr("class", "area")
                 .attr("d", area)
                .attr("fill",color);
            svg.append("g")
                      .attr("class", "x axis")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                      .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .call(yAxis)
            .append("text")
              .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
              .attr("y", 6)
              .attr("dy", ".71em")
              .style("text-anchor", "end")
              .text("Revenue (M)");
```

Currently I am getting on my X axis as .011,.012,013,.014  I need as 2011,2012,2013,2014
I am new to D3 js so dnt know much about how to use scales??Please Help anyone..Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see where you're defining the `parseDate` function, but I don't see anywhere that you're using it. Have you perhaps omitted some code? Presumably you mean to iterate through your data and update the `.Year` property by applying `parseDate()`.

Answer (score 5):

Just add tick Format to your x Axis definition:

```
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(x)
              .orient("bottom")
              .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y")); // <-- format
```

Comment: I have used the given tick format but now it is coming as 1970 in all the values round x axis,,,inspite I have given range and domain,then why it is showing all 1970 in x axis

Comment: @Garima The reason 1970 comes might be your year is not a timestamp, actually you can use ordinal scale in your case.

Comment: Here is a example using year as xAxis:http://fiddle.jshell.net/ramseyfeng/5dussf43/

Comment: @huan feng ,,My date(year) value is a string ,I have tried it to use ordinal but it didnt work,, :-(...Is there any way to represent year string on x axis for area chart

Answer (score 4):

In v4, it'd be something like this:

```
d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(d3.timeYear.every(1))
```

Comment: As of v4.x this is by far the easiest solution. Thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

huan feng is right. The time scale is treating your year(implicitly converted to an int) as timestamps. To force the scale to operate on the year, create Date objects specifying the year in it. Basically change the following line:

```
x.domain(d3.extent(localData, function (d) { return d.Year; }));
```

to

```
x.domain(d3.extent(localData, function (d) { return new Date(parseInt(d.Year),0); }));
```

You may then use Klaujesi's solution to change the tickFormat.