# How to create line chart with JSON data using D3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-hooks

I am working with D3.js and react-hooks to create charts, So I tried creating one `Line` chart by searching around and got one.

- But the one I am working with is using Sample data, here in my case I have JSON data.
- I have made the charts responsive as well using `resize-observer-polyfill` this library.
- Now I am struggling to implement it with JSON data, to renders it with dynamic data.

**What I did**

```
const svgRef = useRef();
const wrapperRef = useRef();
const dimensions = useResizeObserver(wrapperRef); // for responsive

// will be called initially and on every data change
useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select(svgRef.current);
    const { width, height } =
        dimensions || wrapperRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();

    // scales + line generator
    const xScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, data.length - 1]) // here I need to pass the data
        .range([0, width]);

    const yScale = scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, max(data)])
        .range([height, 0]);

    const lineGenerator = line()
        .x((d, index) => xScale(index))
        .y((d) => yScale(d))
        .curve(curveCardinal);

    // render the line
    svg
        .selectAll('.myLine')
        .data([data])
        .join('path')
        .attr('class', 'myLine')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('d', lineGenerator);

    svg
        .selectAll('.myDot')
        .data(data)
        .join('circle')
        .attr('class', 'myDot')
        .attr('stroke', 'black')
        .attr('r', (value, index) => 4)
        .attr('fill', (value, index) => 'red')
        .attr('cx', (value, index) => xScale(index))
        .attr('cy', yScale);

    // axes
    const xAxis = axisBottom(xScale);
    svg
        .select('.x-axis')
        .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`)
        .call(xAxis);

    const yAxis = axisLeft(yScale);
    svg.select('.y-axis').call(yAxis);
}, [data, dimensions]);

    <React.Fragment>
        <div ref={wrapperRef} style={{ marginBottom: '2rem' }}>
            <svg ref={svgRef}>
                <g className="x-axis" />
                <g className="y-axis" />
            </svg>
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
```

Here I am not able to pass the data, my data is below

```
[
  { anno: 2014, consumo: 300, color: "#ff99e6" },
  { anno: 2015, consumo: 290, color: "blue" },
  { anno: 2016, consumo: 295, color: "green" },
  { anno: 2017, consumo: 287, color: "yellow" },
  { anno: 2018, consumo: 282, color: "red" },
  { anno: 2019, consumo: 195, color: "white" }
]
```

Here in my data I have color for each data, which I want to show in each dot generated.

[working code sandbox of line chart](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-bush-yogqi?file=/src/useResizeObserver.js)

**Similarly I tried doing bar chart and it is working fine**

I did some dynamic rendering to labels, when we resize the window the labels gets adjusted automatically.

[Here is the full working bar chart what I am trying to implement to line chart](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-haze-tfger?file=/src/App.js)

I have also commented the lines where I am doing what.

**Edit / Update**

I ahve been following @MGO 's answer and it helped me Alot, but still I am facing issue to align labels and filling the color to dots.

[image: as you can see the labels are overlapping to each other]

actually it is obvious that it will overlap because of the text size, but just to overcome that In bar chart I have used below code

```
 const tickWidth = 40;
const width = xScaleLabels.range()[1];
const tickN = Math.floor(width / tickWidth);
const keepEveryNth = Math.ceil(xScaleLabels.domain().length / tickN);

const xScaleLabelDomain = xScaleLabels
  .domain()
  .filter((_, i) => i % keepEveryNth === 0);
xScaleLabels.domain(xScaleLabelDomain);
```

what it is doing is when the device size is small it will  filter some labels and will not show labels.

And also I am using below code to give color

```
.attr("fill", ({ color }) => color)
```

But is is not taking any color, but it is taking by default black color.

I have data to show as label as `July.9.2021 11:18:28` but I only want to show time so what I am doing in my bar chart code is below

```
const xScaleLabels = scaleBand()
        .domain(
            data.map(
                ({ sensorValueAddedTime }) => sensorValueAddedTime.split(' ')[2]  // this I am using to show only time
            )
        )
        .range([0, dimensions.width])
        .padding(padding);
```

Same I am trying to do with Line chart, In a simple way, I do not want to change this to any time and all.

This is the second data, so basically the Answer I got is only working for 1st data not for second, I want that to be dynamic if data comes in any of these format I want to show.

`sensorValueAddedTime` I want to show on x-axis
`sensorValue` On y-axis

I have already added my bar chart full working code, Same I want to do with line chart.

```
    [
    {
      sensorValue: 32,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 10:56:22",
      color_code: null,
      condition: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    },
    {
      sensorValue: 32,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 10:56:23",
      color_code: null,
      condition: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    },
    {
      sensorValue: 35,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 11:17:51",
      color_code: null,
      condition: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    },
    {
      sensorValue: 35,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 11:17:52",
      color_code: null,
      condition: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    },
    {
      sensorValue: 36,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 11:18:08",
      color_code: null,
      condition: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    },
    {
      sensorValue: 36,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 11:18:09",
      color_code: null,
      condition: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    },
    {
      sensorValue: 38,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 11:18:27",
      condition: null,
      color_code: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    },
    {
      sensorValue: 38,
      sensorValueAddedTime: "July.9.2021 11:18:28",
      condition: null,
      color_code: null,
      __typename: "sensorData"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: To clarify, do you want to produce a line chart with the array that has {anno: 2014, consumo: 300, color: "#ff99e6" }, or with the array in the Codesandbox? I've answered using the data provided in the Codesandbox. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the original example from  Muri's [D3 with React Hooks video series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR8xtl_IbCw) `data` is a flat single-dimensional array: `[10, 25, 30, 40, 25, 60]`.

In the new array you're providing (`data1`), we're asking D3 to render a chart based on an *array of objects*. So when we pass `data1` in as a prop to our chart function, we need to do a little more work to access the values inside of our array of objects.

We'll need to scale the data values into the appropriate ranges. The original example looked up the values by their index in the array. We're going to need to access the values in the objects contained in the `data1` array based on those objects' keys. Like this, to create our scales:

```
const yScale = scaleLinear()
                  .domain([0, max(data, (d) => d.sensorValue)])
                  .range([height, 0]);

// scale the values of sensorValueAddedTime into the range for our x axis values
// since it's a date you'll need to convert the strings to Date objects:

const xScale = scaleTime()
                 .domain([
                   new Date(min(data, (d) => d.sensorValueAddedTime)),
                   new Date(max(data, (d) => d.sensorValueAddedTime))
                  ])
                 .range([0, width]);
```

And like this, in our `lineGenerator` function:

```
const lineGenerator = line()
      .x((d) => xScale(new Date(d.sensorValueAddedTime))
      .y((d) => yScale(d.sensorValue));
```

You'll notice above that if we're going to use `scaleTime()`, we'll have to convert `sensorValueAddedTime` into a value that D3 can make sense of -- right now there's an extra space in the string in your object, but if you strip that space [you can convert to a Date object and use `d3.scaleTime()`.](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaletime)

[There's an updated, working Sandbox that's rendering this data to a line chart with additional comments here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-wilson-3k9hv?file=/src/BrushChart.js:1325-1633)

**Update: OP was asking to plot a different set of data and asked that the points "appear in that order".**

**[There's a different working Sandbox rendering this different set of data to a line chart correctly here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-vaughan-pg99v?file=/src/BrushChart.js:1550-1594)**

It seems like what you're asking for -- the "line graph version of the bar chart" may not produce what you're after. Just talking it through:

If you use the index position of each object on your xScale, like this:

```
const xScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, data.length - 1])
      .range([0, width]);
```

that will produce a pretty boring chart -- because you're saying "put a dot at every whole number representing the index of the array". In other words, a dot at 1, at 2, at 3, and so on.

For this chart, we should choose meaningful values in our data -- like `data1.anno` -- and use those to communicate.

For example:

Scaling the values into the range according to the index positions of the array and plotting them according to their index position, like this:

```
const xScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, data.length - 1])
      .range([0, width]);
    

....chart code....

.attr("cx", (value, index) => xScale(index))
```

Produces this plot:

[image: plot of points by index position in array]

**Solution**

Scaling the values of the data into the range and plotting the points according to their values. We can use [d3's `extent` method](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-extent), like this:

```
const xScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain(extent(data, (d) => d.anno))
      .range([0, width]);

    const yScale = scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, max(data, (d) => d.consumo)])
      .range([height, 0]);

....chart code...

.attr("cx", (value) => xScale(value.anno))
.attr("cy", (value) => yScale(value.consumo));
```

Produces this plot:

[image]

`data1.anno` is clearly a year. The option to parse the years as date obects is a good one. `var parse = d3.timeParse("%Y")`, then use this to set the domain of your time scale: `.domain([parse(minDate), parse(maxDate)])`, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32428122/what-scale-to-use-for-representing-years-only-on-x-axis-in-d3-js/32429353).

Otherwise, if you'd like to preserve that value on the x-axis and not treat it as a Date object, you can use Javascript's `toFixed()` method to remove the decimal places, remove the comma delimiter with [`d3.format`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-format) and change the number of ticks that appear with [`axis.ticks()`](https://observablehq.com/@d3/axis-ticks).

That produces this chart:

[image]

To generate a line with these points, use the values in the data, not the indexes.

```
const lineGenerator = line()
      // .x((d, index) => xScale(index)) // old
      // .y((d) => yScale(d)) // old
      .x((d) => xScale(d.anno)) // new
      .y((d) => yScale(d.consumo)) // new
      .curve(curveCardinal);
```

That produces this chart:

[image]

Finally, if your goal is to assign the color value in each object to a point, access those values and assign their values to the fill, like this:

```
.attr("fill", (value) => value.color)
```

That produces this chart:

[image]

**[Here's the working sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-vaughan-pg99v?file=/src/BrushChart.js:986-1152)**

Hope this helps! ✌️

Comment: i have updated code sandbox with proper data, please check once

Comment: actually i do not want to change that ti date object, I want it to show how data is coming in that order

Comment: Got it, the answer is now updated. tl;dr, you will still need to access the values in each object in the array. Let me know if that answers the question and mark it if it does. Here's the working sandbox with the different dataset https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-vaughan-pg99v?file=/src/BrushChart.js:1550-1594

Comment: Hey i tried your code, now if i am trying to do with previous data that is  `July.9.2021 10:56:22` date is coming in this form and i want to show in same format so it is not working, actually i do not want to do any other thing just what ever data i am getting i want to show on that order so data is not same for every case as my data is dynamic so in one place i am getting like above, so `tofixed` is causing issue, when i removed that the chart is not populated clearly.

Comment: That's expected, since `sensorValueAddedTime` is a string. The value in the other object (`anno`) is a number. 

The answer above correctly describes how to chart those values with D3 per the original question. Reading that value in as a Date object would solve the problem in both cases.

It seems like your question may actually not be about D3 and instead have more to do with processing and normalizing data from different sources -- "Given objects that have values of different types, how can I process the JSON so that the values can be represented in the same dimension?"

Comment: Here's the Sandbox that shows how you can turn the value you want to plot on the x-axis as a Date object. I will add it to the original answer.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-haslett-7vobh?file=/src/BrushChart.js